# Problem getting qmake project dependencies to work

Tags: qt, project, qmake

I have the following directory structure:

```
 - project
     - test.pro
     - test2
         - test2.pro
```

test.pro looks like this:

```
# ...
SUBDIRS = test2
```

The problem is that when I run:

> `qmake test.pro`
>   `make`

...it only builds `test` and not `test2`.

How come `test2` isn't getting built as well? What do I have to do to tell one Qt project to build another one first?

Answer (score 4):

Adding to SUBDIRS has no effect for any TEMPLATE other than subdirs, and you cannot have multiple TEMPLATEs in a single .pro file.  In other words, you can't have a single .pro file to both build some binaries and invoke some subdirs projects.

You need one top-level .pro file which *only* contains subdirs.  For example, your test.pro could be:

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs
SUBDIRS = test1 test2
```

... and you would then have subdirectories for test1 and test2.

If you don't want to reorganize your code into a subdirectory, you can also put the names of .pro files (instead of directory names) into SUBDIRS.  For example, your test.pro could be:

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs
SUBDIRS = test1.pro test2
```

... where test1.pro may exist in the same directory as test.pro, and have the usual TEMPLATE=app stuff.